# Fetching fields from overriden request header in Controller

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, web-services

I am overriding the request header in the android side by the following code

```
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("density", String.valueOf(density));
        params.put("width", String.valueOf(phone_width));
        System.out.println("VALUE_PARAM::::"+params);
        return params;
```

I want to fetch the width and density in my controller in the java code side.

What is the optimal way to fetch them?
Request Method GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write controller method as below

```
@GetMapping("/your_path")
public ResponseEntity<String> getHeadersMethod(@RequestHeader("density") String density, @RequestHeader("width") String width) {
    // code that uses the density and width variables
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(density+":"+width, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: i want to use width and density to return something else in controller, don't want to return these attributes

Comment: yes. this is just the idea. As I mentioned in comment write your code to use width and density and return your object from there. density and width should be available in method parameters.